# Trouble with parsing table data in perl

Tags: html, regex, perl, parsing

I have a long htdoc of similar pattern which goes on like this:

```
<td class="MODULE_PRODUCTS_CELL " align="center" valign="top" height="100">
<table width="100" summary="products"><tr>
<td align="center" height="75">
<a href="/collections.php?prod_id=50">
<img src="files/products_categories50_t.txt" border="0" alt="products" /></a><\br>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">
<a href="/collections.php?prod_id=50"><strong>Buffer</strong><br />
</a>
<td>
</tr></table>
</td>
```

In the above html I want to extract:

1. `collections.php?prod_id=50`
2. `files/products_categories50_t.txt`
3. `Buffer`

I have tried this code to begin with,

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
my $filename =  'sr.txt';

open(FILENAME,$filename);
my @str = <FILENAME>;
chomp(@str);
#print "@str";

foreach my  $str(@str){    
     if ($str =~/<td class(.*)<a href(.*?)><\/td>/) {
         print "*****$2\n";
     }    
}
```

This code is a trial one. However it brings only last occurrence and not each occurrence. Why?

Comment: If you want us to make the effort to solve you problem then you should probably make the effort to ensure that it's formatted in a way to make it as easy to read as possible.

Comment: Sample text from sr.txt would help.  Also your second capture looks a little weird `.*?`

Comment: The reason it only matches the last occurrence is your use of the greedy .* following the class. If you used the non-greedy variant, .*?, then you'd get the first occurrence...

Comment: ...or, better, use `[^>]*` instead of `.*` or `.*?` because you're looking for any number of non-`>` characters, not for any number of any character at all. The negated character class version is often faster to process than a non-greedy "match anything", plus it more clearly expresses your intent to human readers.

Comment: @Chris, No, that answer is **NOT** enough to answer all such questions. It is a joke; it does not explain things. If you really believe that is the right approach to answering people, go ahead and make it a real answer so we can vote on it. Otherwise it’s just mindless parroting, and it doesn’t help the user one bit.

Comment: @tchrist - Disagree. I obviously don't believe it should be an answer, since I didn't post it as one, and as a comment is it perhaps more humorous to others, but it essentially the same thing the OP is doing, and the answer does say "use an HTML parser" which is the correct way to handle the situation (albeit after a lot of perhaps unnecessary setup). Comments are different from answers. That's why the comment I made has 6 upvotes and the answer someone else posted has only one (and two downvotes).

Comment: @tchrist - the point is that UNLESS you have the regex-foo of a level achieved may be by a half dozen of people (yourself included), you should not venture into the minefield that is HTML regex parsing. Your answers poviding the parsing examples are wonderful for people wishing to achieve regex enlightenment (i know I bookmarked two recent ones for further study), but they are not practical to a random Joe Deveoper needing to do the task with a mininmum of fuss (and thus avoid inevitable bugs in their regexes)

Comment: @DVK: I’m mortally uncomfortable with the hypocrisy of giving “do as I say, not as I do” advice. People here nearly always mischaracterize both problem *and* solution, which niggles me. They use *“parse”* far too freely, meaning no more than suss out or munge. Querents never explain the true constraints, and folks giving answers nearly never do, either. **Rote repetition of soundbytes w/o deeper understanding oversimplifies into lies and leads to mindless cargo-cult programming.** Regexes are great for lexing x/ʜᴛᴍʟ, plus work well on well-constrained fragments. Parsing is a different matter.

Comment: @DVK: You may well be more often right than wrong if you always assume people are idiots than under the contrary assumption. But you will also piss **way** more people off that way. Just saying’.

Comment: @tchrist - can't argue with that. I'm just saying that different answers may work better for different audiences, though a good caveat making the answer more technically precise is definitely a great idea even for "cargo cult" (also known as "use CPAN, don't reinvent the bicycle") answers.

Answer (score 58):

## SUMMARY

Using patterns on little, limited pieces of reasonably well-defined pieces of HTML is quick and easy. But using them on an entire document containing fully general, open-ended HTML of unforeseeable quirks is, while theoretically possible, in practice much too hard compared with using someone else’s parser that’s already been written for that express purpose.  See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933611/can-extended-regex-implementations-parse-html/4934590#4934590) for a more general discussion on using patterns on XML or HTML.

### Naïve Regex Solution

You’ve asked for a regex solution, so I will provide you such.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use 5.10.0;
use strict;
use warnings;

$/ = undef;
$_ = <DATA>;   # read all input

while (m{ < \s* img [^>]* src \s* = \s* ['"]? ([^<>'"]+) }gsix) {
    print "IMG SRC=$1\n";
}

while (m{ < \s* a [^>]* href \s* = \s* ['"]? ([^<>'"]+) }gsix) {
    print "A HREF=$1\n";
}

while (m{ < \s* strong [^>]* > (.*?) < \s* / \s* strong \s* > }gsix) {
    print "STRONG=$1\n";
}

__END__

<td class="MODULE_PRODUCTS_CELL" align="center" valign="top" height="100">
<table width="100" summary="products">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" height="75">
            <a href="/collections.php?prod_id=50">
                <img src="files/products_categories50_t.txt" border="0" alt="products" />
            </a>
            <br/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <a href="/collections.php?prod_id=50">
                <strong>Buffer</strong><br />
            </a>
        <td>
    </tr>
</table>
</td>
```

That program, when run, produces this output:

```
IMG SRC=files/products_categories50_t.txt
A HREF=/collections.php?prod_id=50
A HREF=/collections.php?prod_id=50
STRONG=Buffer
```

If you are quite certain that works for the particular specimen of HTML that you wish it to, then by all means use it.  Notice several things that I do which you didn’t.  One of them is not dealing with the HTML a line at a time.  That virtually never works.

However, this sort solutions works only on **extremely limited** forms of valid HTML.  You can only use it when you can guarantee that the HTML you’re working with really looks like what you expect it to.

The problem is that it quite often does not look all neat and tidy.  For these situations, you are strongly advised to use an HTML parsing class.  However, no one seems to have shown you the code to do that.  That’s not very helpful.

### Wizard-Level Regex Solution

And I’m going to be one of them myself. Because I am going to show you a more general solution for approaching what I believe your take to be, but unlike anyone else who ever posts on Stack Overflow,  I’m going to use regexes to do it, **just to show you that it can be done, but that you *do not* wish to do it this way:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use 5.10.0;
use strict;
use warnings;

$/ = undef;
$_ = <DATA>;   # read all input

our(
    $RX_SUBS,
    $tag_template_rx,
    $script_tag_rx,
    $style_tag_rx,
    $strong_tag_rx,
    $a_tag_rx,
    $img_tag_rx,
);

# strip stuff we aren't supposed to look at
s{ <!    DOCTYPE  .*?         > }{}sx; 
s{ <! \[ CDATA \[ .*?    \]\] > }{}gsx; 

s{ $style_tag_rx  .*?  < (?&WS) / (?&WS) style  (?&WS) > }{}gsix; 
s{ $script_tag_rx .*?  < (?&WS) / (?&WS) script (?&WS) > }{}gsix; 
s{ <!--     .*?        --> }{}gsx;

while (/$img_tag_rx/g) {
    my $tag = $+{TAG};
    printf "IMG tag at %d: %s\n", pos(), $tag;
    while ($tag =~ 
        m{ 
            $RX_SUBS  
            \b src (?&WS) = (?&WS) 
            (?<VALUE> 
                (?: (?&quoted_value) | (?&unquoted_value) ) 
            )
        }gsix) 
    {
        my $value = dequote($+{VALUE});
        print "\tSRC is $value\n";
    } 

} 

while (/$a_tag_rx/g) {
    my $tag = $+{TAG};
    printf "A tag at %d: %s\n", pos(), $tag;
    while ($tag =~ 
        m{ 
            $RX_SUBS  
            \b href (?&WS) = (?&WS) 
            (?<VALUE> 
                (?: (?&quoted_value) | (?&unquoted_value) ) 
            )
        }gsix) 
    {
        my $value = dequote($+{VALUE});
        print "\tHREF is $value\n";
    } 
} 

while (m{
            $strong_tag_rx  (?&WS) 
            (?<BODY> .*? )  (?&WS) 
            < (?&WS) / (?&WS) strong (?&WS) > 
        }gsix) 
{
    my ($tag, $body) = @+{ qw< TAG BODY > };
    printf "STRONG tag at %d: %s\n\tBODY=%s\n", 
            pos(), $+{TAG}, $+{BODY};
} 

exit;

sub dequote { 
    my $string = shift();
    $string =~ s{
        ^
        (?<quote>   ["']      )
        (?<BODY> 
            (?: (?! \k<quote> ) . ) *
        )
        \k<quote> 
        $
    }{$+{BODY}}gsx;
    return $string;
}

sub load_patterns { 

    $RX_SUBS = qr{ (?(DEFINE)

        (?<any_attribute> 
            \b \w+
            (?&WS) = (?&WS) 
            (?:
                (?&quoted_value)
              | (?&unquoted_value)
            )
        )

        (?<unquoted_value> 
            (?&unwhite_chunk) 
        )

        (?<quoted_value>
            (?<quote>   ["']      )
            (?: (?! \k<quote> ) . ) *
            \k<quote> 
        )

        (?<unwhite_chunk>   
            (?:
                # (?! [<>'"] ) 
                (?! > ) 
                \S
            ) +   
        )

        (?<WS>     \s *   )

        (?<end_tag>          
            (?&html_end_tag)
          | (?&xhtml_end_tag)
        )

        (?<html_end_tag>       >  )
        (?<xhtml_end_tag>    / >  )

      ) # end DEFINE

    }six;

    my $_TAG_SUBS = $RX_SUBS . q{ (?(DEFINE)

        (?<attributes>
            (?: 
                (?&WS) 
                (?&one_attribute) 
            ) *
        )

        (?<one_attribute>
            (?= (?&legal_attribute) )
            (?&any_attribute) 
        )

        (?<optional_attribute>
            (?&permitted_attribute)
          | (?&deprecated_attribute)
        )

        (?<legal_attribute> 
            (?: (?&required_attribute)
              | (?&optional_attribute)
              | (?&standard_attribute)
              | (?&event_attribute)
              # for LEGAL parse only, comment out next line 
              | (?&illegal_attribute)
            )
        )

        (?<optional_attribute>
            (?&permitted_attribute)
          | (?&deprecated_attribute)
        )

        (?<illegal_attribute> \b \w+ \b )

        (?<tag>
            (?&start_tag)
            (?&WS) 
            (?&attributes) 
            (?&WS) 
            (?&end_tag)
        )

      ) # end DEFINE

    };  # this is a q tag, not a qr

    $tag_template_rx = qr{ 

            $_TAG_SUBS

        (?<TAG> (?&XXX_tag) )

        (?(DEFINE)
            (?<XXX_tag>     (?&tag)             )
            (?<start_tag>  < (?&WS) XXX \b      )
            (?<required_attribute>      (*FAIL) )
            (?<standard_attribute>      (*FAIL) )
            (?<event_attribute>         (*FAIL) )
            (?<permitted_attribute>     (*FAIL) )
            (?<deprecated_attribute>    (*FAIL) )

        ) # end DEFINE
    }six;

    $script_tag_rx = qr{   

            $_TAG_SUBS

        (?<TAG> (?&script_tag) )
        (?(DEFINE)
            (?<script_tag>  (?&tag)                )
            (?<start_tag>  < (?&WS) style \b       )
            (?<required_attribute>      type )
            (?<permitted_attribute>             
                charset     
              | defer
              | src
              | xml:space
            )
            (?<standard_attribute>      (*FAIL) )
            (?<event_attribute>         (*FAIL) )
            (?<deprecated_attribute>    (*FAIL) )
        ) # end DEFINE
    }six;

    $style_tag_rx = qr{    

            $_TAG_SUBS

        (?<TAG> (?&style_tag) )

        (?(DEFINE)

            (?<style_tag>  (?&tag)  )

            (?<start_tag>  < (?&WS) style \b       )

            (?<required_attribute>      type    )
            (?<permitted_attribute>     media   )

            (?<standard_attribute>
                dir
              | lang
              | title
              | xml:lang
            )

            (?<event_attribute>         (*FAIL) )
            (?<permitted_attribute>     (*FAIL) )
            (?<deprecated_attribute>    (*FAIL) )

        )  # end define

    }six;

    $strong_tag_rx = qr{    

            $_TAG_SUBS

        (?<TAG> (?&strong_tag) )

        (?(DEFINE)

            (?<strong_tag>  (?&tag)  )

            (?<start_tag>  
                < (?&WS) 
                strong 
                \b       
            )

            (?<standard_attribute>
                class       
              | dir 
              | ltr 
              | id  
              | lang        
              | style       
              | title       
              | xml:lang
            )

            (?<event_attribute>
                on click    
                on dbl click        
                on mouse down       
                on mouse move       
                on mouse out        
                on mouse over       
                on mouse up 
                on key down 
                on key press        
                on key up
            )

            (?<required_attribute>      (*FAIL) )
            (?<permitted_attribute>     (*FAIL) )
            (?<optional_attribute>      (*FAIL) )
            (?<deprecated_attribute>    (*FAIL) )

        ) # end DEFINE

    }six; 

    $a_tag_rx = qr{         

            $_TAG_SUBS

        (?<TAG> (?&a_tag) )

        (?(DEFINE)
            (?<a_tag>  (?&tag)  )

            (?<start_tag>  
                < (?&WS) 
                a 
                \b       
            )

            (?<permitted_attribute>
                charset     
              | coords      
              | href        
              | href lang   
              | name        
              | rel 
              | rev 
              | shape       
              | rect
              | circle
              | poly        
              | target
            )

            (?<standard_attribute>
                access key  
              | class       
              | dir 
              | ltr 
              | id
              | lang        
              | style       
              | tab index   
              | title       
              | xml:lang
            )

            (?<event_attribute>
                on blur     
              | on click    
              | on dbl click        
              | on focus    
              | on mouse down       
              | on mouse move       
              | on mouse out        
              | on mouse over       
              | on mouse up 
              | on key down 
              | on key press        
                on key up
            )

            (?<required_attribute>      (*FAIL) )
            (?<deprecated_attribute>    (*FAIL) )
        ) # end define
    }xi;

    $img_tag_rx = qr{           
        $_TAG_SUBS
        (?<TAG> (?&image_tag) )
        (?(DEFINE)

            (?<image_tag> (?&tag) )

            (?<start_tag>  
                < (?&WS) 
                img 
                \b       
            )

            (?<required_attribute>
                alt
              | src
            )

            # NB: The white space in string literals 
            #     below DOES NOT COUNT!   It's just 
            #     there for legibility.

            (?<permitted_attribute>
                height
              | is map
              | long desc
              | use map
              | width
            )

            (?<deprecated_attribute>
                 align
               | border
               | hspace
               | vspace
            )

            (?<standard_attribute>
                class
              | dir
              | id
              | style
              | title
              | xml:lang
            )

            (?<event_attribute>
                on abort
              | on click
              | on dbl click
              | on mouse down
              | on mouse out
              | on key down
              | on key press
              | on key up
            )

        ###########################

        ) # end DEFINE

    }six;

}

UNITCHECK { load_patterns() } 

__END__

<td class="MODULE_PRODUCTS_CELL" align="center" valign="top" height="100">
<table width="100" summary="products">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" height="75">
            <a href="/collections.php?prod_id=50">
                <img src="files/products_categories50_t.txt" border="0" alt="products" />
            </a>
            <br/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <a href="/collections.php?prod_id=50">
                <strong>Buffer</strong><br />
            </a>
        <td>
    </tr>
</table>
</td>
```

That program, when run, produces this output:

```
IMG tag at 304: <img src="files/products_categories50_t.txt" border="0" alt="products" />
        SRC is files/products_categories50_t.txt
A tag at 214: <a href="/collections.php?prod_id=50">
        HREF is /collections.php?prod_id=50
A tag at 451: <a href="/collections.php?prod_id=50">
        HREF is /collections.php?prod_id=50
STRONG tag at 491: <strong>
        BODY=Buffer
```

### The Choice Is Yours — Or *Is* It?

Both those solve your problem with regexes. It is *possible* that you will be able to use the first of my two approaches.  I cannot say, because like seemingly all such questions asked here, you haven’t told us enough about the data for us (and perhaps also you) to know for sure whether the naïve approach will suffice.

When it doesn’t, you have two choices.

1. You can either use the more robust and flexible approach offered by my second technique. Just make certain that you understand it in all its aspects, because otherwise you won’t be able to maintain your code — and neither will anybody else.
2. Use an HTML parsing class.

I find it unlikely that even 1 person in a 1000 would reasonably make the first of those two choices.  In particular, I find it extremely unlikey that someone who asks for help with regexes as simple as those in my first solution would be a person capable of managing the regexes given in my second solution.

Which really leaves you with only one “choice” — if I may use that word so loosely.

Answer (score 5):

You may find that parsing this would be easier with [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) than regexes. Your data could do with being somewhat more semantically structured though, but I guess that might be out of your hands.

Have a look at [XML::XPath](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aXPath).

[The 10-Minute XPath Tutorial](http://oreilly.com/perl/excerpts/system-admin-with-perl/ten-minute-xpath-utorial.html) from *Automating System Administration with Perl* also might be handy.

Comment: It would be great if its in perl regex

Comment: @user510749: You said it would be great if this were a perl regex. I dunno for sure that that follows, but I *have* given you two different perl regex approaches in my answer elsewhere on this page.  Whether they’re great or not I leave to your judgement. BTW, if you edit your user profile, you can give yourself a name of your choosing, not just @user510749.

Comment: I find [HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath](http://p3rl.org/HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath) has a much more useful API than XML::XPath.

Comment: I wasn't familiar with H::T::XPath, it does look a bit more useful in this case. But the use of XPath rather than regexes was what I was trying to get at.

Comment: @daxim: That’s been my experience as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!perl

while(<DATA>) {
    print "$1\n" while (m/href="([^"]+)/gi)
}

__DATA__
<td class="MODULE_PRODUCTS_CELL " align="center" valign="top" height="100">
<table width="100" summary="products">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" height="75">
            <a href="/collections.php?prod_id=50">
                <img src="files/products_categories50_t.txt" border="0" alt="products" />
            </a>
            <br/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <a href="/collections.php?prod_id=50">
                <strong>Buffaer</strong><br />
            </a>
        <td>
    </tr>
</table>
</td
```

Comment: If you’re going to downvote this solution, you should say why, since it appears to do what the OP requested.

Comment: yeah, what's up with that? :(

Comment: To paraphrase Knuth : anybody parsing HTML with a regex is living in state of sin.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code only reads the first line of your input. If you want to iterate through all the lines of your input, you should use this:

```
while($str = <FILENAME>) {
   chomp $str;
}
```

Assuming your input is well formated, and the href attribute always comes after the 'a' tag, and the src attribute always follows 'img' tag, and you don't have spaces in your URL's, and you don't have more than one strong tag per line, then you could use the following:

```
open(FILENAME, 'sr.txt') || die "$!\n";
while($str = <FILENAME>) {
   chomp $str;
   if( $str =~ /<a href=\"(\S+)"/ ) {
      print "$1\n";
   } elsif( $str =~ /<img src="(\S+)"/ ) {
      print "$1\n";
   } elsif( $str =~ /<strong>(.*)<\/strong>/ ) {
      print "$1\n";
   }
}
```

This code is quite ugly, but it does what you want. Parsing with XPath, as suggested by ptomli would be easier, and more elegant.

Comment: all other things being equal, it does look a bit odd to see `$_ =~` in those lines.

Comment: @tchrist Edited the solution to match the $str variable used in the question