# Regular expression to grab form tag content doesn't work

Tags: html, regex, parsing, multiline

I am trying to grab contents/tags inside form tag using preg_match_all, here is the regular expression

```
/<form\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/form>/i
```

But i wonder, why it doesn't work! Any idea?

Comment: hmmm....odd. can you give us the source you're searching?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @Mark: -1 for mindless and inappropriate parroting of a noninstructive answer you only like because it makes you laugh, not because it helps anyone. Bart’s answer addressed the question. You just hid behind a comment so we can’t vote you down for insolence and uselessness.

Comment: @tchrist +10 if I could. @Mark, posting link to "the thread" is uninformative parrot-like behavior. Feel free to post an actual answer explaining why it's not advisable to do such a thing, or link to an answer that does this. The post you now linked to does not explain this.

Comment: @tchrist, @Bart Kiers, It does if you read past the accepted answer.

Comment: @Mark: Then why the devil didn’t you link to the answer that actually describes things instead of to one that does not?  You’d get a **−①** for that, too.  Perhaps you could add a more germane comment to correct the old one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the `.` (DOT) does not match line breaks. If you enable DOT-ALL with the `s` modifier, it does match those  chars:

```
/<form\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/form>/is
```

Realize  that you won't be able to match something like:

```
<form>
   ...

   <!-- </form> -->

   ...
</form>
```

to name just one of the possibilities.

Answer (score -1):

[Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML. Use an HTML parser.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: **−⓵:** Uniformative, mindless parrot-like behaviour ought not be rewarded. @marcog, if you would care to edit your answer into a coherent and informative answer that compares the pros and cons of varying approaches, or at least provide a proper link to such, I shall withdraw my downvote. Until then, your and everyone else’s answer like this gets my downvote for its disrespectful and noeducative slap-down almost Pavlovian in parrot-like reaction. **Try helping people instead.**

Comment: @tchrist What you ask for is already provided in the linked thread. As for the actual question, it needs an example of it failing as Keng asked for.

Comment: @marcog always willing to help someone make the 3k mark for close vote privileges.

Comment: @tchrist, This is helping against bad designs. Besides that the link provides answers that can parse html with regex if you realy want. Read it first, comment later.

Comment: @Mark: What you linked to is wrong. It is just the comedy response. Link to something that talks about this from a technical perspective, not from a laugh-getting one. It is **FALSE** to claim *“one cannot use regexes to parse HTML.”*  One certainly **can,** if not [in one way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284176/doubt-in-parsing-data-in-perl-where-am-i-going-wrong/4286326#4286326), perhaps [in another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231382/regular-expression-pattern-not-matching-anywhere-in-string/4234491#4234491).  Those are why **not** to do so. Say when and where you *should!*

Comment: @tchrist The second answer in that link gives an example of where it might make sense. The third answer explains why you can't. The fourth answer gives a well-tested, somewhat robust regex that the author *still* shows isn't perfect. The fifth answer gives an example of an HTML parser. Lots of useful stuff. Just cause we linked to the first answer, doesn't mean we meant only that to be read. Read on further as I already said.

Comment: @marcog: The answer @Bart Kiers gave is the **correct answer to the OP’s question,** whereas yours is not. Can you really not see that? Even if yours were the right answer — and it isn’t — telling people to read through miles of posting to find the relevant parts, which you did not condescend to provide for them — is worse than not answering at all.

Comment: @tchrist If there was a single correct answer to questions like this, life as a programmer would be too easy it'd be boring. In other words, there is no correct answer and mine is an alternate view which I believe in and you clearly do not. Doesn't mean you should be running around calling people wrong with in such a case were both answers are reasonable.

Comment: @marcog: I firmly believe that expending no more effort that it takes to link to a gigantic post, instead of actually answering the question, does people a disservice. I am tired of the parroting.

Comment: @tchrist You're beginning to overlook what I'm actually saying and repeating the same point you've already made.

Comment: @marcog, @tchrist, I hope you'll join me in voting to close this question. Even if you dislike the top answer that @marcog links to, I think we can agree that answer #3 over there is very descriptive, accurate, and helpful.

Comment: @ marcog, would you tell me whats the problem to use regular expression to parse html? I believe other parsers that parse html use regular expression.

Comment: @Musa: To quote one of the answers to the other question: "HTML is a Chomsky Type 2 grammar (context free grammar) and RegEx is a Chomsky Type 3 grammar (regular expression). Since a Type 2 grammar is fundamentally more complex than a Type 3 grammar - you can't possibly hope to make this work." Most parsers use regular expressions -- for only the first level of parsing, which is to break up the input into **tokens** (which in the case of XML are smaller units of text than a single tag). After they've broken up the text into tokens, they *need* a **context free grammar** to capture structure.

Comment: @Musa: The *right way* to parse HTML or XML (and the only way that captures all of the corner cases) is to use an HTML parser library that will create a document tree for you, and then you use **XPath** to find the right part of the document.