# filtering <form> from html text using regular expression

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am getting an whole html page from an ajax request as text (`xmlhttp.responseText`)

Then filtering the text to extract a html `form` from that text  and everything inside that form.

I wrote an regex :

```
text.match(/(<form[\W\w]*<\/form>)/gim)
```

As i am not an expert in regex, so i cant be sure will it work in every scenario and get everything inside the `form` tag?

Is there a better way that i can say **everything** in regex?
so that the regex will look like

```
 text.match(/(<form[__everything_syntaxt_here__]*<\/form>)/gim)
```

Comment: Are you looking for the internal `form` tag stuff, or from `<form..> to </form>` or both ?

Comment: everything inside  the `<form> ......</form>` tag and also the beginning and end tag too.@sln

Comment: see this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288102/regular-expression-to-grab-form-tag-content-doesnt-work

Comment: I would discourage you from using regexes for this at all. You can use `responseXML` or make a `documentFragment` or hidden `<div>` and approach the response as what it is, a HTML page with a DOM tree. So then you simply get `parsedDom.getElementsByTagName('form')[0]` and do what you want with it.

Comment: @funkwurm thanks for your concern. I have tried that and failed as the html comes with so much complex tags,meta tags and internal script the default parser of old browser (currently fighting stupid  with IE5 :O ) failed  to parse them. That why i am trying to help the old person here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having to deal with IE *5*, you poor soul.

A quick answer to your question *Is `[\W\w]` really the best way to match absolutely everything?*

**Yes**, JavaScript does not support the `s` modifier to make `.` match newlines. Doing `[\W\w]` basically tells the regex: *"Match anything that is a word character, or anything that isn't a word character"*, you can see that absolutely every character falls in either of those categories.

**But**, if you want a more reliable solution to deal with `<!-- html comments -->` and multiple forms on a page, best approach is something like explained in **[this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25402157/2684660)** but changed for HTML.

This is what I would use:

```
<!--(?:(?!-->)[\w\W])*-->|(<form(?:(?:(?!<\/form>|<!--)[\w\W])|(?:<!--(?:(?!-->)[\w\W])*-->))*</form>)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Look at the [Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/dV1y5Gtox5IboR8w) to see what matches you actually get. In JavaScript you can then expect the first capture group. If it's empty then that was just to get rid of the commented form like explained **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23589174/regex-pattern-to-match-excluding-when-except-between/23589204#23589204)**.

Comment: its even more than i need. Thanks.

Comment: Matches `<formica><form></form>` and `<form a="</form>`"></form> and <script>var a="`<form>"</script><form></form>`

Comment: @sln which is indeed why you shouldn't parse HTML with regexes. But if the use-case is 1 user that is stuck on a slow IE 5 and so you can't use DOM manipulations or a server-side solution, this probably does a good job. [This](https://www.debuggex.com/r/EehQ3iScgXRz1_fA) extended version addresses your specific matches but you'll always run into something. For instance nested forms, improper `<form action="forgottenquote.php>` and what if the `<form>` is actually entirely inside a JavaScript variable so you _would_ want the content of `<script>var a="<form>"; </script>`?

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
function stripForm(s) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = s;
  var scripts = div.getElementsByTagName('form');
  var i = scripts.length;
  while (i--) {
    scripts[i].parentNode.removeChild(scripts[i]);
  }
  return div.innerHTML;
}
function getForm(s) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = s;
  var scripts = div.getElementsByTagName('form');
  var i = scripts.length;
    var ret="";
  while (i--) {
    ret += scripts[i].innerHTML;
  }
  return ret;
}
var a = 'before Form <form action="" method="post"> <input type="text" /> <input type="text" /> <input type="text" /> </form><br/> after form';
alert(getForm(a));
alert(stripForm(a));
console.log(stripForm(a));
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/09w733wf/)

Comment: yah its make a good sense. But i think you have noticed that i'have said that  the **whole** html page is coming as a response. so it may include tags like `<html>,<meta>,<head>,<body>` even internal `scripts` and `style` too. So i don't think it will be a good idea to set the whole text as innetHTML inside a `div` then parse it.