# regex selection

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string like this.

```
<p class='link'>try</p>bla bla</p>
```

I want to get only `<p class='link'>try</p>`
I have tried this.
`/<p class='link'>[^<\/p>]+<\/p>/`

But it doesn't work.

How can I can do this?
Thanks,

Comment: Regular expressions and HTML? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Although you certainly *can* [parse HTML with regexes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284176/doubt-in-parsing-data-in-perl-where-am-i-going-wrong/4286326#4286326), you probably don’t want to if it is generic HTML.  It’s fine for “captive” HTML though; just be incredibly wary of it in its “wild” state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If that is your string, and you want the text between those `p` tags, then this should work...

```
/<p\sclass='link'>(.*?)<\/p>/
```

The reason yours is not working is because you are adding `<\/p>` to your not character range. It is not matching it literally, but checking for not each character individually.

Of course, it is mandatory I mention that there are better tools for parsing HTML fragments (such as a HTML parser.)

Comment: @Matti - Agreed! In fact, I'll make a bot that upvotes all answers that match  `/\>[^<>]*\bHTML\b[^<>]*\bParser\b[^<>]*\</` [(!)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%28!%29)

Comment: That’s a very fragile pattern.  [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284176/doubt-in-parsing-data-in-perl-where-am-i-going-wrong/4286326#4286326) for how careful you really have to be if you are hellbent on using regexes on generic HTML.

Comment: @tchrist It sure is, but looking at the example the OP gave, it seemed they were wanting to know why their particular regex was not working. As for the regex/HTML debate, please refer to my last sentence :)

Comment: I just didn’t know why you used `\s` without using `\s+`, etc.

Comment: @tchrist Just trying to point out the OP's obvious mistake. Your points are very valid though :)

Answer (score 0):

```
'/<p[^>]+>([^<]+)<\/p>/'
```

will get you "try"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you used this block: `[^<\/p>]+` intending to match anything except for `</p>`. Unfortunately, that's not what it does. A `[]` block matches any of the characters inside. In your case, the `/<p class='link'>[^<\/p>]+` part matched `<p class='link'>try</`, but it was not immediately followed by the expected `</p>`, so there was no match.

Alex's solution, to use a non-greedy qualifier is how I tend to approach this sort of problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make one less specific to any particular tag.

```
(<[^/]+?\s+[^>]*>[^>]*>)
```

this returns:

`<p class='link'>try</p>`