# RegEx to parse complex xml javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, regex, parsing

I am working in a restricted Javascript environment and don't have an xml parser or dom access.

The format goes like this:

```
<gd:phoneNumber rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#mobile">206 555 1212</gd:phoneNumber>
```

I need to get string[] value: mobile, 206 555 1212

The values will be different every time but the tags always the same.

Then I need to be able to replace the values for example: home, 555-555-5555

Can this be done in regEx?

Comment: Jamie Zawinski, 1997 : "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems." ... :)

Comment: What part stays the same in the context of atrib/val? What about google.com/g/...#mobile? Any other attr/val's in that tag? Is this in the context of xml?

Comment: Yes, of course it can be done with regexes.  However, Javascript’s regex implementation is not very powerful; it cannot even cope with Unicode correctly.  Still, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284176/doubt-in-parsing-data-in-perl-where-am-i-going-wrong/4286326#4286326) may give you some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

There is [fast-xml-parser](https://naturalintelligence.github.io/fast-xml-parser/) which is based on regex only. You can include that in your project.

```
//var xml2json = require('fast-xml-parser').parse;
var jsonObj = xml2json('<gd:phoneNumber rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#mobile">206 555 1212</gd:phoneNumber>', {ignoreNameSpace : true});
console.log(jsonObj.phoneNumber); // "206 555 1212"
```

Or if you make the regex yourself, I'll suggest you to use regex to capture matching string as @DaveWard suggested in his answer instead of using `replace`.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at 
http://www.webreference.com/js/column5/methods.html

Comment: That is helpful but I just can't get the syntax right. jquery is

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have so far and it works but is there a better way?

```
"<gd:phoneNumber rel=http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#mobile>206 555 1212</gd:phoneNumber>".replace(/#.*</g, '#home>111-111-1111<')
```

Returns:

```
"<gd:phoneNumber rel=http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home>111-111-1111</gd:phoneNumber>"
```

So I can inject the new values

```
"<gd:phoneNumber rel=http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#mobile>206 555 1212</gd:phoneNumber>".match(/#.*</g)[0].replace(/[#<]/g, "").split(/>/)
```

returns:
["mobile", "206 555 1212"]

allowing me to get the values

Answer (score 0):

This retrieves the matches and performs replacements:

```
var testString = '<gd:phoneNumber rel=http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#mobile>206 555 1212</gd:phoneNumber>';

var regex = /.*#(\w+)">(.*)</i;

// matches[1] will be "mobile" and matches[2] will be "206 555 1212"
var matches = regex.exec(testString);

// Replace #mobile with #home
testString = testString.replace(matches[1], 'home');

// Replace the phone number with 555 555 5555
testString = testString.replace(matches[2], '555 555 5555');
```

Those simple replacements will work as long as there's no overlap between those values and the rest of the XML element's contents (e.g. if the schemas.google.com URL contained the string `mobile` somewhere before `#mobile`, this wouldn't work).  Long as that's the case, this is the easier way to do the replacements.