# Detect text between some tags

Tags: php, regex, tags

I am trying to detect text between 3 or 4 tags and I have no idea how - USING PHP.
I know that I am supposed to use regex but thats too hard for my mind :X

If you can explain me how to do it / give me example of what I need it will be great!

I am trying to detect code between `<script>` tag > which mean if I got `<script type="text/javascript">` it will detect also. if there's `<script src="...">` then it wont detect the text between (shouldnt be text between).

same with  script ^ if there's `<style type="text/css">` it will detect the text between too

and I also want to detect text between style="detect text here" artitube.

Last tag I want to text between is `<?php ?>`. (php can be also in upper case, so I dont want the regex to be case sensitive).

Thanks for the helpers!!!

Comment: No, you're not supposed to use a regex.

Comment: What is wrong with using regular expressions for this?

Comment: @Kaltas: It's just a meme on Stackoverflow. People are confounding parsing and extracting, and don't gauge the use case and problem potential objectively. (So be careful with mentioning it whenever HTML is at topic. For other structured languages it usually goes unnoticed though.)

Comment: I see - well as every problem it needs to be evalueated carefully.

Comment: @Kaltas: Yes, and it’s a bad meme, too, one which @SLaks should not be propagating, nor should anybody else either. Regexes are perfectly fine for tame ᴀᴋᴀ captive ᴀᴋᴀ limited ᴀᴋᴀ known HTML strings. Only with *entirely* open-ended HTML, especially where you have an entire web page, does it [become rather more difficult — but still not impossible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284176/doubt-in-parsing-data-in-perl-where-am-i-going-wrong/4286326#4286326). Note that that link is trying to convince folks **not** to use regexes for a full parse/extraction; everybody reads that posting wrong.

Comment: @SLaks: If they are “not supposed to”, then it would be more helpful to show them what they “are supposed to” use — and how — then just to slap them down. That doesn’t help anyone. It’s kinda rude, even.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using regular expressions you could write something like:

```
<?php
$html = <<<EOF
<script type="text/javascript">
    function xyz() { alert('some alert'); }
</script>
EOF;

preg_match('/<script.*>(.*)<\/script>/sU', $html, $matches);

var_dump($matches)
?>
```

Comment: works for <style> tag and <script> tag, altough it detect text between script tag with src (it doesnt really matter). but <?php ?> is special case and same about style arttiube.

Comment: It is for sure - this is just a quick example of where to start. I can elaborate on this if you're interested.

Comment: Yes please! btw I tried preg_match('/style="(.*)"/sU', $html, $matches); to detect text between style artitube and it half worked oO wanted to detect the text here > style="gfhfgh" so I did foreach ($matches as  $line) using my regex and I got 2 lines - 1 with style="gfhfgh" and one with gfhfgh. wierd oO

Comment: If you take a look at the documentation you'll see that $matches always look like this - you always get the text that matches the full pattern at $matches[0] and matched subpatterns in next indices.

Comment: O ok, thanks then my regex was right :D, what's the regex for <?php ?>
this one didnt work properly > preg_match('/<?php(.*)?>/sU', $html, $matches); I am pretty sure I need to add something before the ? (question mark)

Comment: Yes I knew it! added backslash before the two question marks so it looks like this> preg_match('/<\?php(.*)\?>/sU', $html, $matches); and it worked! thank you very much Kaltas!

Comment: I have a small improvement (you need to match all variants as <? <?php and <?PHP). Try using this: /<\?(php|)(.*)\?>/isU ... Also you'll probably need preg_match_all to match all code blocks. You're welcome, I'm glad to help :).

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions aren't best suited for parsing HTML. For good reasons why, see the question [**Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-regex)

You'll have an easier time loading the  HTML into the [DOM XML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) classes, then you can perform XPath queries to extract the tags you want.

For example, try something like this to get all the `<script>` tags which don't have a src attribute...

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile("myfile.html");

$xpath=new DOMXPath($doc);

//find script elements which don't have a src attribute
$scriptNodes=$xpath->query("script[not(@src)]");
foreach ($scriptNodes as $scriptNode) {

    //do something here...

}
```

Comment: What if it is not valid HTML?

Comment: The HTML support is supposed to be pretty forgiving, but you'll just need to try it.

Comment: Paul: that's true but it's not 100% safe. But if it works in this particular case your approach is better than regexps for sure.

Comment: this is the code in myfile.html > <html><head><title>test</title><script>function alerthello(){alert("hello");}</script></head><body>
<input type="button" onclick="alerthello()" value="Click me" /></body></html> used your code to detect the text between the script tag and echo it, it didnt work.. am I missing something?

Comment: @Ron: If that is all there is to your HTML, then it is pretty trivially handled by regexes.

Comment: @Paul: That example uses rare, esoteric features of HTML which one is highly unlikely to require accommodation for in these tame examples. And they, of course, can be dealt with if need be.

Comment: @tchrist, I got about 30 files, the average number of lines is 300+-, I just gave an example...