# What is wrong with my regular expression?

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

How can i go about getting the value eg

1. `<div class="detail">   Hello  </div>`
2. `<div class="detail">   World  </div>`

   ```
        string x = " <div class="results-list clearfix">
                    <div class="detail">   Hello
                    </div> 
          </div>
          <div class="results-list clearfix">
                    <div class="detail">   World
                    </div> 
          </div>          
        ";

       String pattern = @"<div class=""results-list clearfix"">(?<Content>[^<]*)</div>";

       Regex rx = new Regex(pattern,RegexOptions.Multiline);
       Match m = rx.Match(x);

       while (m.Success)
       {
           string zz =  m.Groups["Content"].Value;
           m = m.NextMatch();
       }
   ```

Comment: Your `string x` value is not valid C# - you need to use a verbatim string literal (start with `@`) and escape the inner quotes `"`.

Comment: Have a look at this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not

Comment: @Banang: Wrong.  Take a look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933611/can-extended-regex-implementations-parse-html/4934590#4934590).

Comment: @tchrist I do not agree that my comment is wrong at all. I linked to a thread that explains why parsing html using regular expressions is a *bad idea*. You linked to an answer written by you where you say  that it is a bad idea, but that it *can be done*. These are not conflicting ideas.

Comment: @Banang: Your linked thread mistakenly asserts *Entire HTML parsing is not possible with regular expressions, since it depends on matching the opening and the closing tag which is not possible with regexps.* That is not in the least bit true with modern patterns, as the very last line of my own cited answer trivially proves by using `s/\\((?:[^()]*+|(?0))*\\)//g` to delete all opening and closing parens and their contents, **recursively**. It is therefore no longer a theoretical matter, merely a practical one: the theory allows it while the practice often advises against it.

Comment: @Banang: Furthermore, even if it *were* true (and it’s not), it would not apply because it is talking about the parsing of “entire HTML”, which is nothing like the case here.

Comment: @tchrist I will not argue with you over this. I find your tone utterly unpleasant and argumentative. If you care so deeply about this issue that you feel the need to be verbose, there is nothing I can say to make you feel any differently.

Comment: @Banang - While tchrist may be a bit zealous sometimes, he is definitely correct. Today the relation between regular expressions and regular languages is mostly rhythmic (i.e.: they sound similar). A short example is `(.*)\1`, which is supported by most flavors and clearly isn't regular, and and other extensions like recursive matching make them even more powerful. The idea that you cannon match a construct because it isn't *regular* is often stated, but is simply wrong.

Comment: @Kobi, thank you for that explanation. tchrist could definitly learn from your communication skills.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is your problem `""results-list clearfix""`.  As you are using a literal string, you can remove the extra `"`'s.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad idea to use regular expressions for this kind of parsing. Use an XML parser for this particular scenario. I suggest LINQ to XML, i.e.  `XElement.Parse(...)`

Do not forget to wrap you html in a single root element though.

Comment: **This  is not true!**  It is *perfectly reasonable* to use regexes on small bits of captive ᴀᴋᴀ tame X/HTML like this. It’s far more reasonable that the alternative, which has about a 10,000:1 blowup and is fiddly to boot. This is the perfect situation for applying regexes to X/HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern with SingleLine option:

```
string pattern = "<div\\sclass=\"results-list clearfix\">\\s*(?<Content><div[^>]*>.*?</div>)"
```