# regular expression to extract data from html page

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep, lynx

I want to extract all anchor tags from html pages. I am using this in Linux.

```
lynx --source http://www.imdb.com | egrep "<a[^>]*>"
```

but that is not working as expected, since result contains unwanted results

```
<a class="amazon-affiliate-site-name" href="http://www.fabric.com">Fabric</a><br>
```

I want just

```
<a href >...</a>
```

any good way ?

Comment: Look that post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not

Comment: Don't use regex to parse html. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: What is the use of giving comedy comments, not even genuine answers, to a technical question?

Answer (score 5):

If you have a `-P` option in your grep so that it accepts PCRE patterns, you should be able to use better regexes.  Sometimes a minimal quantifier like `*?` helps. Also, you’re getting the whole input line, not just the match itself; if you have a `-o` option to grep, it will list only the part that matches.

```
egrep -Po '<a[^<>]*>'
```

If your grep doesn’t have those options, try

```
perl -00 -nle 'print $1 while /(<a[^<>]*>)/gi'
```

Which now crosses line boundaries.

To do a real parse of HTML requires regexes subtantially more more complex than you are apt to wish to enter on the command line.  [Here’s one example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231382/regular-expression-pattern-not-matching-anywhere-in-string/4234491#4234491), and [here’s another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284176/doubt-in-parsing-data-in-perl-where-am-i-going-wrong/4286326#4286326). Those may not convince you to try a non-regex approach, but they should at least show you how much harder it is in the general case than in specific ones.

This answer shows why [all things are possible, but not all are expedient.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933611/can-extended-regex-implementations-parse-html/4934590#4934590)

Answer (score 2):

why can't you use options like `--dump` ?

```
lynx --dump --listonly http://www.imdb.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `grep -Eo`:

```
$ echo '<a class="amazon-affiliate-site-name" href="http://www.fabric.com">Fabric</a><br>' | grep -Eo '<a[^>]*>'
<a class="amazon-affiliate-site-name" href="http://www.fabric.com">
```

But please read the answer that MAK linked to.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's some examples of why you should not use regex to parse html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-rege).

To extract values of `'href'` attribute of anchor tags, run:

```
$ python -c'import sys, lxml.html as h
> root = h.parse(sys.argv[1]).getroot()
> root.make_links_absolute(base_url=sys.argv[1])
> print "\n".join(root.xpath("//a/@href"))' http://imdb.com | sort -u
```

Install `lxml` module if needed: `$ sudo apt-get install python-lxml`.

#### Output

```
http://askville.amazon.com
http://idfilm.blogspot.com/2011/02/another-class.html
http://imdb.com
http://imdb.com/
http://imdb.com/a2z
http://imdb.com/a2z/
http://imdb.com/advertising/
http://imdb.com/boards/
http://imdb.com/chart/
http://imdb.com/chart/top
http://imdb.com/czone/
http://imdb.com/features/hdgallery
http://imdb.com/features/oscars/2011/
http://imdb.com/features/sundance/2011/
http://imdb.com/features/video/
http://imdb.com/features/video/browse/
http://imdb.com/features/video/trailers/
http://imdb.com/features/video/tv/
http://imdb.com/features/yearinreview/2010/
http://imdb.com/genre
http://imdb.com/help/
http://imdb.com/helpdesk/contact
http://imdb.com/help/show_article?conditions
http://imdb.com/help/show_article?rssavailable
http://imdb.com/jobs
http://imdb.com/lists
http://imdb.com/media/index/rg2392693248
http://imdb.com/media/rm3467688448/rg2392693248
http://imdb.com/media/rm3484465664/rg2392693248
http://imdb.com/media/rm3719346688/rg2392693248
http://imdb.com/mymovies/list
http://imdb.com/name/nm0000207/
http://imdb.com/name/nm0000234/
http://imdb.com/name/nm0000631/
http://imdb.com/name/nm0000982/
http://imdb.com/name/nm0001392/
http://imdb.com/name/nm0004716/
http://imdb.com/name/nm0531546/
http://imdb.com/name/nm0626362/
http://imdb.com/name/nm0742146/
http://imdb.com/name/nm0817980/
http://imdb.com/name/nm2059117/
http://imdb.com/news/
http://imdb.com/news/celebrity
http://imdb.com/news/movie
http://imdb.com/news/ni7650335/
http://imdb.com/news/ni7653135/
http://imdb.com/news/ni7654375/
http://imdb.com/news/ni7654598/
http://imdb.com/news/ni7654810/
http://imdb.com/news/ni7655320/
http://imdb.com/news/ni7656816/
http://imdb.com/news/ni7660987/
http://imdb.com/news/ni7662397/
http://imdb.com/news/ni7665028/
http://imdb.com/news/ni7668639/
http://imdb.com/news/ni7669396/
http://imdb.com/news/ni7676733/
http://imdb.com/news/ni7677253/
http://imdb.com/news/ni7677366/
http://imdb.com/news/ni7677639/
http://imdb.com/news/ni7677944/
http://imdb.com/news/ni7678014/
http://imdb.com/news/ni7678103/
http://imdb.com/news/ni7678225/
http://imdb.com/news/ns0000003/
http://imdb.com/news/ns0000018/
http://imdb.com/news/ns0000023/
http://imdb.com/news/ns0000031/
http://imdb.com/news/ns0000128/
http://imdb.com/news/ns0000136/
http://imdb.com/news/ns0000141/
http://imdb.com/news/ns0000195/
http://imdb.com/news/ns0000236/
http://imdb.com/news/ns0000344/
http://imdb.com/news/ns0000345/
http://imdb.com/news/ns0004913/
http://imdb.com/news/top
http://imdb.com/news/tv
http://imdb.com/nowplaying/
http://imdb.com/photo_galleries/new_photos/2010/
http://imdb.com/poll
http://imdb.com/privacy
http://imdb.com/register/login
http://imdb.com/register/?why=footer
http://imdb.com/register/?why=mymovies_footer
http://imdb.com/register/?why=personalize
http://imdb.com/rg/NAV_TWITTER/NAV_EXTRA/http://www.twitter.com/imdb
http://imdb.com/ri/TRAILERS_HPPIRATESVID/TOP_BUCKET/102785/video/imdb/vi161323033/
http://imdb.com/search
http://imdb.com/search/
http://imdb.com/search/name?birth_monthday=02-12
http://imdb.com/search/title?sort=num_votes,desc&title_type=feature&my_ratings=exclude
http://imdb.com/sections/dvd/
http://imdb.com/sections/horror/
http://imdb.com/sections/indie/
http://imdb.com/sections/tv/
http://imdb.com/showtimes/
http://imdb.com/tiger_redirect?FT_LIC&licensing/
http://imdb.com/title/tt0078748/
http://imdb.com/title/tt0279600/
http://imdb.com/title/tt0377981/
http://imdb.com/title/tt0881320/
http://imdb.com/title/tt0990407/
http://imdb.com/title/tt1034389/
http://imdb.com/title/tt1265990/
http://imdb.com/title/tt1401152/
http://imdb.com/title/tt1411238/
http://imdb.com/title/tt1411238/trivia
http://imdb.com/title/tt1446714/
http://imdb.com/title/tt1452628/
http://imdb.com/title/tt1464174/
http://imdb.com/title/tt1464540/
http://imdb.com/title/tt1477837/
http://imdb.com/title/tt1502404/
http://imdb.com/title/tt1504320/
http://imdb.com/title/tt1563069/
http://imdb.com/title/tt1564367/
http://imdb.com/title/tt1702443/
http://imdb.com/tvgrid/
http://m.imdb.com
http://pro.imdb.com/r/IMDbTabNB/
http://resume.imdb.com
http://resume.imdb.com/
https://secure.imdb.com/register/subscribe?c=a394d4442664f6f6475627
http://twitter.com/imdb
http://wireless.amazon.com
http://www.3news.co.nz/The-Hobbit-media-conference--full-video/tabid/312/articleID/198020/Default.aspx
http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/redirect-home/internetmoviedat
http://www.audible.com
http://www.boxofficemojo.com
http://www.dpreview.com
http://www.endless.com
http://www.fabric.com
http://www.imdb.com/board/bd0000089/threads/
http://www.imdb.com/licensing/
http://www.imdb.com/media/rm1037220352/rg261921280
http://www.imdb.com/media/rm2695346688/tt1449283
http://www.imdb.com/media/rm3987585536/tt1092026
http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000092/
http://www.imdb.com/photo_galleries/new_photos/2010/index
http://www.imdb.com/search/title?sort=num_votes,desc&title_type=tv_series&my_ratings=exclude
http://www.imdb.com/sections/indie/
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0079470/
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0079470/quotes?qt0471997
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1542852/
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1606392/
http://www.imdb.de
http://www.imdb.es
http://www.imdb.fr
http://www.imdb.it
http://www.imdb.pt
http://www.movieline.com/2011/02/watch-jon-hamm-talk-butthole-surfers-paul-rudd-impersonate-jay-leno-at-book-reading-1.php
http://www.movingimagesource.us/articles/un-tv-20110210
http://www.npr.org/blogs/monkeysee/2011/02/10/133629395/james-franco-recites-byron-to-the-worlds-luckiest-middle-school-journalist
http://www.nytimes.com/2011/02/06/books/review/Brubach-t.html
http://www.shopbop.com/welcome
http://www.smallparts.com
http://www.twinpeaks20.com/details/
http://www.twitter.com/imdb
http://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/features/2011/03/lauren-bacall-201103
http://www.warehousedeals.com
http://www.withoutabox.com
http://www.zappos.com
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract values of 'href' attribute of anchor tags you may also use xmlstarlet after converting HTML to XHTML using HTML Tidy (Mac OS X version released on 25 March 2009):

```
curl -s www.imdb.com | 
tidy -q -c -wrap 0 -numeric -asxml -utf8 --merge-divs yes --merge-spans yes 2>/dev/null |
xmlstarlet sel -N x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" -t -m "//x:a/@href" -v '.' -n | 
grep '^[[:space:]]*http://' | sort -u | nl
```

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS X you may also use the command line tool linkscraper:

```
linkscraper http://www.imdb.com
```

see: http://codesnippets.joyent.com/posts/show/10772