# Extract contents of paragraph tag using a Perl one liner

Tags: html, perl, tags, expression

I would like to match the contents of a paragraph tag using a perl reg ex one liner. The paragraph is something like this:

```
<p style="font-family: Calibri,Helvetica,serif;">Text I want to extract</p>
```

so I have been using something like this:

```
perl -nle 'm/<p>($.)<\/p>/ig; print $1' file.html
```

Any ideas appreciated

thanks

Comment: Why regular expressions? That aren't generally well suited to HTML parsing. `perl -MHTML::TreeBuilder -e'print HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_file("filename.html")->find("p")->as_text'`

Comment: @David: I use HTML::TreeBuilder quite a bit in programs, but I confess it never occurred to me use it in a one-liner!

Comment: This works perfectly... any idea how you would pass *.html instead of filename.html? I would like get all paragraphs from files in a directory.

Comment: print map {HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_file($_)->find("p")->as_text} grep {/.*\.html} File::Util->list_dir('/some/dir'); or the like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$` in matching part means 'end-of-the-string' and you need also match all in p-tag non-greedy way:

`perl -nle 'm/<p.*?>(.+)<\/p/ig; print $1' test.html`

Comment: This does the trick more or less, although comments on the futility of parsing HTML with regular expressions are also valid. I have to use regular expressions because I don't have the root password to the box I'm trying to do this on, which precludes the installation of any nice HTML::TreeBuilder libraries.

Comment: @John, you don't need root to install modules. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540640/how-can-i-install-a-cpan-module-into-a-local-directory

Comment: @tadmc, thanks for that, unfortunately I have never never much success with installing perl modules locally.

Answer (score 5):

Mandatory [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) to what happens when you try to parse HTML with regular expressions.

David Dorward's comment, to use [HTML::TreeBuilder](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML::TreeBuilder), is a good one.
Another good way to do this, is by using [HTML::DOM](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML::DOM):

```
perl -MHTML::DOM -e 'my $dom = HTML::DOM->new(); $dom->parse_file("file.html"); my @p = $dom->getElementsByTagName("p"); print $p[0]->innerText();'
```

Comment: Mandatory links [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231382/regular-expression-pattern-not-matching-anywhere-in-string/4234491#4234491) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284176/doubt-in-parsing-data-in-perl-where-am-i-going-wrong/4286326#4286326) showing what happens when *I* – but maybe not *you* ☺ – try to parse HTML with regexes. [Here’s one more explaining](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933611/can-extended-regex-implementations-parse-html/4934590#4934590) that just because you can doesn’t mean you should.