# Is HTML a context-free language?

Tags: html, grammar, language-theory, sgml

Reading [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1758162#1758162) [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933611/can-extended-regex-implementations-parse-html/4934590#4934590) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not/590789#590789) made me think about the theoretical nature of HTML.

I'm not talking about XHTML-like code here. I'm talking about stuff like this crazy piece of markup, which is perfectly valid HTML(!)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html<head>
<title//
<p ltr<span id=p></span</p>
</>
```

So given the enormous complexity that SGML injects here, is HTML a context-free language? Is it a formal language anyway? With a grammar?

What about HTML5?

<sub>I'm new to the concept of formal languages, so please bear with me. And yes, I have read the wikipedia article ;)</sub>

Comment: HTML is not context-free, as valid HTML code requires conditions which a CFG specification cannot handle (like unique `id` attributes etc..)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

*Context Free* is a concept from language theory that has important implications in parser implementation. A *Context Free Language* can be described by a *Context Free Grammar*, which is one in which all rules have a single non-terminal symbol at the left of the arrow:

```
X→δ
```

That simple restriction allows `X` to be substituted by the right-hand side of the rules in which appears on the left without regard to what came before or after. For example, if while deriving or parsing one arrives at:

```
αXλ
```

one is sure that

```
αδλ
```

is also valid. Examples of non-context-free rules would be:

```
XY→δ
Xa→δ
aX→δ
```

Those would require knowing what could be derive arround `X` to determine if a rule applies, and that leads to non-determinism (what's around `X` would also like to know what it derives to), which is a no-no in parsing, and in any case we want a language to be well-defined.

The only way to prove that a language is context-free is by proving that there's a context-free grammar for it, which is not an easy task. Most programming languages one comes about are already described by CFGs, so the job is done. But there are other languages, including programming languages, that are described using logic or plain English, so work is required to find if they are context-free.

For HTML, the answer about its context-freedom is yes. SGML is a well defined Context Free Language, and HTML defined on top of it is also a CFL. Parsers and grammars for both languages abound on the Web. At any rate, that [there exist LL(k) grammars](http://www.antlr3.org/grammar/HTML/html.g) for *valid* HTML is enough proof that the language is context-free, because LL is a proven subset of CF.

But the way HTML evolved over the life of the Web forced browsers to treat it as not that well defined. Modern Web browsers will go out of their way to try to render something sensible out of almost anything they find. The grammars they use are not CFGs, and the parsers are far more complex than the ones required for SGML/HTML.

HTML is defined at several levels.

1. At the lexical level there are the rules for valid characters, identifiers, strings, and so on.
2. At the next level is XML, which consists of the opening and closing `<tags>` that define a hierarchical document structure. You can use XML or something XML-like for any purpose, like `Apache Ant` does for build scripts.
3. At the next level are the tags that are valid in HTML, and the rules about which tags may be nested within which tags.
4. At the next level are the rules about which attributes are valid for which tags, languages that can be embedded in HTML like CSS and JavaScript.
5. Finally, you have the semantic rules about what a given HTML document means.

The syntactic part is defined well enough that it can be [verified](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/). The semantic part is much larger than the syntactic one, and is defined in terms of browser actions regarding HTTP, and the [Document Object Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_object_model) (DOM), and how a model should be rendered to the screen.

In the end:

1. Parsing correct HTML is extremely easy (it's context-free and LL/LR).
2. Parsing the HTML that actually exists over the Web is difficult.
3. Implementing the semantics (a browser) over HTML/CSS/DOM is extremely difficult.

Comment: Pretty much yes. So the reasoning for SGML being a CFL goes something like: "The specs ensure a well-defined parse tree. q.e.d." Meaning that the specs can be seen as some kind of informal CFG, right? (Example for browsers not following the rules: [the <p><table> issue](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/last-html-quirk/))

Comment: A well defined parse tree is the product of an unambiguous grammar, be it a CFG or not. Unambiguous means that if a sequence is part of the language, then there exists one an only one parse tree for it. See the edits for the "rules" part.

Comment: I am not sure #2 in your list is quite right.  Valid XHTML is always valid XML, but valid HTML might not be valid XML.  Did you mean SGML/DTD?  One huge difference is the ability to omit/imply end tags in valid HTML (which SGML affords), but the inability to omit/imply end tags in XML.

Comment: Have a look at [hsivonen's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15244772/27009) — he wrote Firefox's HTML parser and worked closely with W3C/WHATWG on defining HTML5 syntax.

Comment: downvoted this answer,(reproducing from previous comments) HTML is not context-free, as valid HTML code requires conditions which a CFG specification cannot handle (like unique `id` attributes etc..), see also [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30697267/is-javascript-a-context-free-language)

Comment: @Nikos Context-free refers to syntax, not semantics. Under your arguments, no programming language is context-free.

Comment: @Apalala, exactly, almost no language is CF, valid HTML requires ids to be unique, this may seem as semantic not needed to specify in grammar, but it is a simple syntactic feature in context-sensitive grammars, so this can be misleading. If one merely wants a CFG to accept a **superset** of language (including non-valid strings), then almost all languages are CF.

Comment: @Apalala, also not confuse *language semantics* with meaning or purpose of a program, a language that requires variables to be defined before used (almost all) is **language semantics**, what the variables actually represent to the programmner is meaning (or purpose)

Comment: The `LL(k) grammar` link may be messed up, because it downloaded a file instead of opening a page. Should there be a `.g` on the end of `http://www.antlr3.org/grammar/HTML/html.g`

Comment: @Laurel The ``.g`` file is an ANTLR grammar file for HTML.

Comment: @Apalala OK. I was expecting it to be a webpage, not a download, which is annoying. I wanted to know what `LL(k)` meant, not download something. (It might be better to link to a page where it can be downloaded, instead of the file itself).

Comment: @Apalala Looking at the linked ANTLR file suggests that HTML's context-free status depends on there being a finite set of valid HTML tags (`<a>`, `<ul>`, etc). Is that correct? Am I right in thinking that arbitrary XML (eg `<foo></foo>` is context-sensitive? The name of the closing tag needs to match the name of the opening tag and you don't know what that name is.

Comment: @Benjamin Indeed. Formally, if the tags are not known in advance, then there cannot be a strict context-free grammar for XML. Yet, if we assume that the matching closing tags are on the semantics level, then XML can be parsed by a CFG. Note that a language like Pascal can be parsed with an LL(1) grammar that doesn't try to check that identifiers are pre-declared and used with operators appropriate to their type. Most parsers used in practice do some semantic checks while parsing, as to detect obvious errors as early in the process as possible.

Comment: What about that? **quote:**
*(There is a formal Doctype definition for HTML) but it is not a context free grammar.
This appear strange at first site - HTML is rather close to XML.There are lots of available XML parsers. There is an XML variation of HTML - XHTML - so what's the big difference?
The difference is that HTML approach is more "forgiving", it lets you omit certain tags which are added implicitly, sometimes omit the start or end of tags etc.On the whole it's a "soft" syntax, as opposed to XML's stiff and demanding syntax.*
**source: taligarsiel.com/Projects/howbrowserswork1.html**

Comment: I will comment, that parsing when it comes to CFG is if we can give rules in CFG, and turning it in to some syntax tree. The semantics are not part of the parsing, it is the interpretation of the syntax tree. compiler theory 101. Tokenization are lexical analysis is technically parsing, but it is done to group the data (words) into groups of tokens, most likely to simplify parsing. Parsing is syntaxical analysis, i.e. how are the document structured. Interpretation is what does the document say. missing closing tags are not a problem for CFG the other way around a little more.

Answer (score 14):

Valid HTML is not a context-free language.

First of all, HTML being an application of SGML is fiction for all practical purposes, so analyzing SGML to answer the question is useless. (However, the SGML fiction probably isn't context-free, either.)

It's more useful to look at the actually defined HTML parsing algorithm. It works on two levels: tokenization and tree building. What HTML calls tokenization is a higher-level operation than what is usually called tokenization when talking about parsers. In the case of HTML, tokenization splits a stream of characters into units like start tags, end tags, comments and text. The tokenizer expands character references. Usually, when talking about parsers, you'd probably treat stuff like the less-than sign as "tokens" and would consider character references to consist of tokens instead of being resolved by the tokenizer.

If you consider the process of splitting the input stream into tokens, that level of the HTML language is regular (*except* for feedback from the tree builder).

However, there are three complications: The first one is that splitting the input stream into tokens is just the first and then there's the tree builder's side that actually cares about the identifiers in the tokens. The second one is that the tree builder feeds back into the tokenizer so that some state transitions made by the tokenizer depend on the state of the tree builder! The third one is that valid documents in the language are defined by rules that apply to the output of the tree builder stage and those rules are complex enough that they can't be fully defined using tree automata (as evidenced by RELAX NG not being expressive enough to describe all the validity constraints).

This isn't an actual proof, but you can probably develop real proofs by working from complications #2 and #3.

Note that the case of invalid documents is not particularly interesting as a question of whether the language is context-free in the sense of there being a context-free grammar that generates all the possible strings with no regard to the parse tree having some intelligible interpretation in terms of the tree that an HTML parser generates. The HTML parser will successfully consume all possible strings, so in that sense, all possible strings are in the "invalid HTML" language.

Edit: Interesting questions left as exercise to the reader:

Is HTML without parse errors but ignoring validity a context-free language?

Is HTML without parse errors and ignoring general validity but with only valid element names allowed a context-free language?

(Complication #2 applies in both cases.)

Comment: Which definition of *Context Free Language* are you using?

Comment: @Apalala, one simple example that HTML is not context-free is the fact that html `id` attributes must be unique, this cannot be described by any CFG,. but is part of HTML specification. see [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30697267/is-javascript-a-context-free-language)

Comment: @NikosM. Things like `id` should be handled by the semantic checker, not by the parser. If you went down that route basically all statically typed languages are not context-free because you need to type check the code.

Comment: @semicolon That's correct: basically all statically typed languages are context-sensitive.

Comment: @MilesRout That is if you consider type-checking to be part of the grammar, because if you don't then whitepsace insensitive languages are typically going to be context-free. And for whitespace sensitive langauge once the lexer inserts the necessary indent / dedent tokens the language generally becomes context-free.

Comment: @semicolon 'Context-free after some arbitrary processing and before other arbitrary processing' isn't really the same as context-free, though. A language is context-free if there is a context-free grammar that accepts *exactly* the syntactically legal programmes. If you only care about accepting a superset, every language is regular.

Comment: Well programs that don't type check are generally considered syntactically valid. The whitespace sensitive thing is a fair point, but I would still call a language context free even if you don't detect type errors in the process.

Comment: I like that you saying that it is not normal tokenization, but then describing normal tokenization. A token is nothing more than a group that some pattern are subscribed to. The HTML can be defined by a CFG, parsing is only checking/generating the structure of the document, not the meaning (semantics). Interpretation are the semantic part of it.

Given how many that are using python and JS, it is baffling how few that know the inner work of an interpreter.

Answer (score 10):

### **NO**

**See Edit Below**

<del>**It depends.**</del>

<del>If you are talking about the subset consisting of only theoretical HTML, then **yes**.</del>

If you also include real life, working HTML that is accessed and used successfully by millions of people daily on many of the top sites on the internet then **NO**.

That is what gives HTML flexibility.  The parsing engine adds tags, closes tags, and takes care of stuff that a theoretical CFG can't do.  If you took automata you might remember that a production rule in a formal grammar cannot be empty (aka epsilon/lambda) on the lhs (left-hand side).  Since the parsing engine is basically using knowledge that a formal grammar and automata couldn't have, it isn't restricted by that and the 'grammar' would have `epsilon/lambda -> result` where the specific epsilon/lambda rule is chosen based on information not available in the grammar.

Since I don't think empty lhs are allowed in any formal grammars, HTML cannot be defined by a formal grammar and is not a formal language at all.

Sure, HTML5 might try to move *towards* a 'more formal' language description but the likelihood that it becomes a context free language in reality (i.e. strings not matched by the grammar are rejected) is about the likelihood XHTML 2.0 takes the world by storm and replaces HTML altogether (XHTML is the attempt they made to make HTML a formal language...it was rejected en masse due to its fragility).

Noteworthy is the fact that HTML 5 is the FIRST HTML standard to be defined before being implemented!  That's right, HTML 1-4 consist of random ideas someone just implemented in a browser, and were collected into standards after the fact based on which features were popularly used and widely implemented.  Then they tried XHTML, which totally failed to be adopted.  Even 'xhtml' on the web is automatically parsed as HTML under almost every circumstance to prevent stuff from just breaking with a cryptic syntax error.  Now you can see how we got here and why it is unlikely to be formalized any time soon.

Lesson:  "In theory, there is no difference between theory and practice.  In practice, there is." - Yogi Berra

EDIT:

Actually, after reading through the documents it turns out that HTML, even according to the HTML 4.01 specification, doesn't actually conform to SGML.  To see for yourself, view the HTML 4.01 Strict document type definition (doctype) at http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd and note the following lines:

> The HTML 4.01 specification includes additional
>       syntactic constraints that cannot be expressed within
>       the DTDs.

So I would say that it is *probably* not a CFL due to those features (although it technically it doesn't disprove the hypothesis that there is some possible PDA that accepts HTML 4.01, it does prevent the argument that SGML is a CFL therefore HTML is a CFL).

HTML5 flip-flops, [abandoning any implied conformance to SGML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Generalized_Markup_Language#HTML), but is presumably describable by a CFG.  However it will still provide best-effort parsing not based on a cfg, so IMO the current situation (i.e. language specification is defined formally, with invalid strings still being accepted, parsed and rendered in a best effort fashion) in this regard is unlikely to change drastically for a long, long, long time.

Comment: I don't know which definition of *Context Free Language* you're using for your analysis. That DTDs cannot express all of HTML means nothing in regards to the original question.

Comment: @Apalala It has everything to do with the original question. Brandon is making the case (which you apparently disagree with) that HTML is not a subset of SGML, so it does not have the same grammar. More than that, his point is that the HTML "standard" (pre 5) is actually kind of an evolutionary mess, and so not really well defined. And DTDs are very much related to the formal definition of the language, making your comment difficult to understand.

Comment: @shovavnik, Please see the most voted up answer in this query. In particular, that there are LL/LR parsers for "correct" HTML is enough proof that the language, as defined, is context free. That the evolution of the Web has required HTML parsers/renderers to dive into Artificial Intelligence to do their thing is awesome, but unrelated to the original question.

Comment: Saying that HTML isn't CFG because people can't write valid HTML is not a proof. I'm not saying that we don't need to take this into account. just that HTML is CFG. but we need to implement a lot of smart error handling if we need to implement a browser/interpreter

Answer (score 5):

HTML5 is different from previous HTML versions in that it strictly defines the parsing behaviour of code that isn't completely correct. Pre-HTML5 parsers vary and each do their best to 'guess' the intention of the code author.

Comment: Sure, but what does that mean in the context of grammar/language theory?

Comment: It means that in reality, it is not context free.

Comment: So you are saying that because people are bad at writing valid HTML, HTML are not CFG?