# Reliably parsing HTML elements using RegEx

Tags: php, html, regex, parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best methods to parse HTML with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html-with-php)

I'm trying to parse a webpage using RegEx, and I'm having some trouble making it work in a reliable manner.

Say I wanted to parse the code that creates a div element, and I want to extract everything between `<div>` and `</div>`. Now, this code *could* just be `<div></div>`, but it could also very well be something like:

`<div class="thisIsMyDivClass"><p>This text is inside the div</p></div>`

How can I make sure that no matter how many characters that are in between the greater-than/less-than signs of the initial div tag and the corresponding last div tag, I'll always **only** get the content in between *them*? If I specify that the number of characters following `<` can be anything from one to ten thousand, I will always be extracting the `>` after ten thousand characters, and thus (most likely, unless there is a lot of code or text in between) retrieve a bunch of code in between that I don't need.

This is my code so far (not reliable for the aforementioned reason):

`/<.{1,10000}>/`

Comment: The best thing would be to use a proper HTML parser. What language are you using?

Comment: I'm using PHP. Would love some good tips on how to do this in the most efficient way.

Comment: Check out [Best methods to parse HTML with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html-with-php)

Comment: You could use something like `<[^>]*>`, but like everyone else is saying, you need a proper parser.

Comment: Just for context, this is one of the most frequently asked questions on StackOverflow, with [this being the most famous version](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/143295).  For the reasons you've stated and others (attributes containing ">" etc.), it is not possible to be 100% reliable with regex.  You can use rough methods like @DevNull's in some cases, but just be aware of the limitations.

Answer (score 3):

Regular expressions describe so called regular languages - or Type 3 in the [Chomsky hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy). On the other hand [HTML is a context free language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175840/is-html-a-context-free-language) which is Type 2 in the Chomsky hierarchy. So: There is no way to reliably parse HTML with regular expressions in general. Use a HTML parser instead. For PHP you can find some suggestions in this question: [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html-with-php)

Answer (score 1):

You will need a Lexical analyser and grammar checker to parse html correctly. RegEx main focus was for searching strings for patterns.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using something like DOM.  I am doing a large scale site with and using DOM like crazy on it.  It works, works good, and with a little work can be extremely powerful.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php