# Python Regular Expression: BackReference

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, backreference

Here is the Python 2.5 code (which replace the word `fox` with a link`<a href="/fox">fox</a>`, and it avoided the replacement inside a link):

```
import re

content="""
<div>
    <p>The quick brown <a href='http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox'>fox</a> jumped over the lazy Dog</p>
    <p>The <a href='http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog'>dog</a>, who was, in reality, not so lazy, gave chase to the fox.</p>
    <p>See &quot;Dog chase Fox&quot; image for reference:</p>
    <img src='dog_chasing_fox.jpg' title='Dog chasing fox'/>
</div>
"""

p=re.compile(r'(?!((<.*?)|(<a.*?)))(fox)(?!(([^<>]*?)>)|([^>]*?</a>))',re.IGNORECASE|re.MULTILINE)
print p.findall(content)

for match in p.finditer(content):
  print match.groups()

output=p.sub(r'<a href="/fox">\3</a>',content)
print output
```

The output is:

```
[('', '', '', 'fox', '', '.', ''), ('', '', '', 'Fox', '', '', '')]
('', '', None, 'fox', '', '.', '')
('', '', None, 'Fox', None, None, None)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/example.py", line 18, in <module>
    output=p.sub(r'<a href="fox">\3</a>',content)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\re.py", line 274, in filter
    return sre_parse.expand_template(template, match)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\sre_parse.py", line 793, in expand_template
    raise error, "unmatched group"
error: unmatched group
```

1. I am not sure why the backreference `\3` wont work.
2. `(?!((<.*?)|(<a.*?)))(fox)(?!(([^<>]*?)>)|([^>]*?</a>))` works see http://regexr.com?317bn , which is surprising. The first negative lookahead `(?!((<.*?)|(<a.*?)))` puzzles me. In my opinion, it is not supposed to work. Take the first match it finds, `fox` in `gave chase to the fox.</p>`, there is a `<a href='http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog'>dog</a>` where matches `((<.*?)|(<a.*?))`, and as a negative lookahead, it should return a FALSE. I am not sure I express myself clearly or not.

Thanks a lot!

(Note: I hate using BeautifulSoup. I enjoy writing my own regular expression. I know many people here will say Regular expression is not for HTML processing blah blah. But this is a small program, so I prefer Regular expression over BeautifulSoup)

Comment: *Why* are you doing this with regex? [Python has such a nice HTML parser.](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) Hint: HTML cannot be parsed with regular expressions. You waste your time trying.

Comment: @Tomalak I add a note to the question. this is a tiny program so it wont worth the effort of importing and learning Beautifulsoup. I enjoy regular expression.

Comment: Susan, it does not matter in the least if you enjoy regular expressions. This is like playing Golf with a hammer and saying *"I don't have the time to learn what's a 9-iron. I enjoy wielding a hammer."* It is completely the wrong tool for the job. The time it took you to a) try and fail to figure out a regex that works and b) write a question here would have been better invested learning BeautifulSoup. It's not that it would be *hard* or anything. You'd very probably be done already.

Comment: Tomalak is spot on... for a tongue-in-cheek discussion that is quite relevant, see [**this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/667301)

Comment: Disclaimer: I enjoy regular expressions, too. [I really do.](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/133/regex?userid=18771) Take my word for it that you are wasting your time. *"I hate using the right tool for the job"* is not a valid argument when asking for help. For a programmer, doubly so.

Comment: @Tomalak: the statement "HTML cannot be parsed with regular expressions" is vague in many ways. At least, define your terms. What do you mean by "parse"? What do you mean by "regular expressions"? (hint: re's in programming languages are not "regular language"), etc...

Comment: @Tomalak Thanks a lot! But I still want to know why the backreference wont work here and why the first negative lookahead works.

Comment: @thg435 The statement is pretty solid. I'm not sure what you mean by "define regular expressions"? How, exactly, is this term a matter of definition? My point is that dissecting a string of HTML into its meaningful parts (i.e. "parsing") is impossible with regular expressions because REs can match *regular* languages. HTML is not a regular language. It's a [context-free language](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5207677/18771), which is a language that REs are not fit to parse.

Comment: @Susan Don't say "thank you" if you don't mean it. ;)

Comment: @Tomalak: modern RE engines can match regular languages and [much more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Patterns_for_non-regular_languages)

Comment: @thg435 Does the regex engine of Python? Besides, even Perl 6's regular expressions are unfit to parse HTML without errors. And besides *all that*, where is the point in not using a parser when you have one available? Everybody can use regex to handle HTML as much as they want, they just should be able to handle regex on a level that allows them not to tell anyone about it.

Comment: @Tomalak: Well, the point one is curiosity that drives progress. The point too is that most "parsers", including BS, actually do use regular expressions to "parse html", whatever that means.

Comment: I agree with thg435. I believe Beautifulsoup uses regular expression heavily.

Comment: @thg435 Wow, I didn't notice we're on the "whatever that means" level already. What a shady way to lead an argument. Let's just hope you're a little ashamed of yourself for pulling such a trick. Anyway. *Of course* BeautifulSoup uses regular expressions. It's the *other code* it contains that makes the difference. If HTML could be parsed with regex alone, HTML parsers would not exist, or would they? I can't believe I must explain this.

Comment: @Tomalak: there's no trick. In order to have a senseless argument, you have to define terms. If by "parsing html" you mean _tokenizing_ (and one of your previous comments makes me think so), then RE's is actually a suitable and even preferred tool. If you mean something else, please explain yourself.

Comment: @Tomalak Instead of arguing RE vs. BS, could you please take a look at my questions? The result is here http://regexr.com/?317bn since you get a badget for regex.

Comment: @thg435 I mean correctly recognizing the individual parts of an HTML string. In order to make changes to them and save them back without breaking the markup. In order to not replace the word `"fox"` in comments. Or attribute values. Undisturbed by invalidly nested markup. I don't mean "tokenizing", which is a small part of a parsing process. I did not know that "parsing" had multiple meanings in CS. Sorry, but "explain your terms" might be an acceptable move in an area that's less well-discussed. Here, it's not.

Comment: @Susan I'm sorry this got out-of-hand a little. I understand your intentions and I'm sure you understand mine as well. Although it looks like I'm just being cocky about it, I'm actually trying to help you. I'm the guy that tries to hand you a 9-iron while you keep asking why you can't seem to go 100 yards with a hammer. I probably could fix your regex. You could also just use a parser. A valid argument *against* doing that has yet to be made.

Comment: @Tomalak: this is where you should have started - just answer the question (if you can). Isn't it a shame for Stackoverflow when a poster gets 100 tons of bullshit for one meaningful answer?

Comment: @thg435 I challenge you to point out the bullshit. Not every question deserves the response the OP had in mind. This does not automatically make the response bullshit. I can answer the question. I won't. Because it would be the Wrong Thing to do. That's a good reason. The  OP could use a parser. She won't. No reason given. That's an indefensible position.

Comment: @Tomalak: this is a programming board. Programming is about solving problems under given constraints, no matter how absurd they appear at the first glance. If you prefer debating about Right and Wrong Things, the philosophy class is right down the hall.

Comment: @thg435 "But I *want* to use a hammer!" - "Sure thing, let me help you with this. This is a Golf training course, after all. We're here to teach you Golf, not philosophy." - Uhm, sorry, doesn't work. If I sense that there's an advanced but seemingly absurd question, I'm happy to help. I go out of my way, spending hours, even days thinking about it. "How can I make my regex work with HTML?" generally does not fall into the advanced questions category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why your expressions don't work, the only thing that I noticed is a lookahead group at the start, which doesn't make much sense to me. This one appears to work well:

```
import re

content="""fox
    <a>fox</a> fox <p fox> and <tag fox bar> 
    <a>small <b>fox</b> and</a>
fox"""

rr = """
(fox)
(?! [^<>]*>)
(?!
    (.(?!<a))*
    </a
)
"""

p = re.compile(rr, re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE | re.VERBOSE)
print p.sub(r'((\g<1>))', content)
```

Comment: "I don't know why your expressions don't work" is part of the reason why using regex for parsing HTML is a bad idea. They always turn into a maintenance nightmare that nobody can fix.

Comment: @thg435 The regular in my code works but the backreference wont work. See here: http://regexr.com/?317bn my regular expression matches what I want but the backreference wont work.

Comment: @Tomalak In this particular case, I am the only person who needs to maintain this tiny piece of code. the problem is I dont know why the backreference wont work.

Comment: @Susan: as seen in your `findall` output, "fox" is group 4, not 3.

Comment: @thg435 Is it indexed from 1? I think it is indexed from 0. so 0,1,2,3

Comment: @thg435 What is the second part of your regular expression? `(?!
    (.(?!<a))*
    </a
)` This negative lookahead does what?

Comment: @thg435 yours wont work. it mathes two extra "fox". See the result here: http://regexr.com?317bt

Comment: @Susan: you've got one extra space in there ;)

Comment: @thg435 Huh? Please post your code here: http://regexr.com/?317bt and post the link back.

Comment: @Susan: there's a space after '?!' that shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't like beautifulsoup, try one of these other (X)HTML parsers:

```
html5lib
elementree
lxml
```

If you ever plan to, or need to, parse HTML (or variant) it is worth learning these tools.