# How to write a regex to get only values of destination btwn destination and departure cities of flight

Tags: performance, loadrunner

Blazedemo is the website can anyone help me on this

Comment: <form action="reserve.php" method="post"><select name="fromPort" class="form-inline">
            <option value="Paris">Paris</option>
            <option value="Philadelphia">Philadelphia</option>
            <option value="Boston">Boston</option>
            <option value="Portland">Portland</option>
            <option value="San Diego">San Diego</option>
            <option value="Mexico City">Mexico City</option>
            <option value="São Paolo">São Paolo</option>
  Like this boundaries are same

Comment: Have you considered pairing Microfocus Tours with LoadRunner?  It would be a better match for the self paced training

Answer (score 0):

HTML is [not a regular language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175840/is-html-a-context-free-language) therefore [using regular expressions for parsing HTML is not the best idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748)

JMeter provides [CSS Selector Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS_Selector_Extractor) which provides way more robust, reliable and readable approach to deal with HTML data.

Example:

[image]

More information:

- [CSS Selector Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php)
- [How to Use the CSS/JQuery Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/cssjquery-extractor)

Comment: Actually I need regular expression for loadrunner web_reg_save_param