# Difficulty using javascript replace function with regex for <span> and </span>...all inclusive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

How can I use `.replace()` with regex for `</?span>`, as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199006/regular-expression-to-match-span-or-span)? (this regex would ideally match `<span>` or `</span>`, including all things within the span)

I have tried a variety of examples, such as:

```
.replace(/</?span>/,"")

.replace(/</?span>/g,"")

.replace(/[</?span>]/,"")

.replace(/[</?span>]/g,"")
```

Comment: The question you linked has a perfectly fitting answer.

Comment: @Katana314 I agree, assuming that the person knows how to use `.match()` with regex in the first place

Comment: Why use regex in the first place? Is the HTML destined for the page? It's easier and safer to remove the nodes than to mess with HTML parsing.

Comment: Just a caution in case it applies here - it is not recommended to parse html with regex. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Why not make it a DOM collection, find the spans, and remove the elements? Clean and no need to deal with regular expressions.

Comment: It's not even so much a matter of regex or not. It's a matter of manually parsing when the browser has a built-in parser that will be far more accurate and efficient.

Comment: can you provide an real example on what you want to achieve, with input and expected output.

Comment: What errors are you getting? Try `.replace(</?span>,"")`, what do you get? Because "here" in `/`<-here + `</?span>` +`/` <-here, are not part of the regex.

Comment: @sln: That's sure not going to work.

Comment: @squint - Yeah, but shouldn't the OP be answering that?

Comment: @sln: Answering what? You're giving the OP code that won't work.

Comment: @squint - What error do you get? And I was helping him solve his own problem without it being spoon fed.

Comment: @sln: If you don't want to spoon feed him, then why should I spoon feed you? If you want to know the error, then test your code.

Comment: @sln, it doesn't work.

Comment: @maudulus-  Try this one `.replace(/<(?:(?:\/?span\s*\/?)|(?:span\s+(?:(?:(?:"[\S\s]*?")|(?:'[\S\s]*?'))|(?:[^>]*?))+\s*\/?))>/g, "")` Report back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Javascript you need to escape `/` because JS uses `/` as regex delimiters and add `[^>]*` to match anything in `span`:

```
.replace(/<\/?span[^>]*>/ig, "")
```

Comment: need to add `g` switch too

Answer (score 2):

Problem with your code is the regular expression ends at the first `/`

```
.replace(/</?span>/,"")
           ^--Thinks this is the closing /
```

It would need to be escaped.

```
.replace(/<\/?span>/,"")
           ^ Use \ to escape it
```

---

But why use a regular expression to remove elements when it nested elements are going to cause you issues. Use the power of the DOM and do not rely on regular expressions.

```js
function removeSpans(htmlStr) {
    var wrapper = document.createElement("div");
    wrapper.innerHTML = htmlStr;
    var spans = wrapper.getElementsByTagName("span");
    while(spans.length) {
      spans[0].parentNode.removeChild(spans[0]);
   }
   return wrapper.innerHTML;
}


var myHTML = "<span>This is a span</span> Some text <span>This is another span</span>";
var cleanedHTML = removeSpans(myHTML);
document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = cleanedHTML;
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```

with jQuery:

```
function removeSpans(htmlStr) {
   var wrapper = $("<div/>").html(htmlStr);
   wrapper.find("span").remove();
   return wrapper.html();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the proper way to clean tags.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you included the `jQuery` tag in your question so I will assume that you can use jQuery. You could use jQuery to solve this issue.

```
$('span').each(function(){
   $(this).replaceWith($(this).text());
});
```

This will look for each `span` element, this element could be any of these:

```
<span>test</span>
<span class="has-a-class" id="also-an-id">a span with any number of attributes</span>
```

And replaces it with the text in that `span`, basically stripping the HTML tag and its attributes:

```
test
a span with any number of attributes
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.replace(/<\/?span.*?>/gi, "")
```

add `?` after `*` to make it non-greedy match.

Comment: That's not going to make a difference.

Comment: @squint - Yeah, but shouldn't you tell him why? And, the reason is relative.

Comment: @sln: Shouldn't he tell why it *would* make a difference?

Comment: Here yes, because it matches for `[^>]*`. Personally I keeps non-greedy as a practice, : ]

Comment: @elaijuh - Its a tricky tradeoff, if its open-ended, the engine scans for the last `>` then works backwards, if it's not open-ended based on subsequent sub-expressions, it could still act in a greedy fashion.

Comment: @sin, can explain it on `/<\/?span.*?>/gi` ?

Comment: `<span data-foo="bar>baz">`

Comment: @squint, for your case, `/<\/?span[^>]*>/ig` doesn't work neither.

Comment: @elaijuh - Here is an example regex that can control those pesky `<>` characters. `<(?:(?:/?span\s*/?)|(?:span\s+(?:(?:(?:".*?")|(?:'.*?'))|(?:[^>]*?))+\s*/?))>` I don't think I could explain it. (Use dot-all modifier)

Comment: @elaijuh: I know that. See my comment above... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27608650/difficulty-using-javascript-replace-function-with-regex#comment43639688_27608650

Comment: @sin - im not gonna try tp understand that anyway thanks all the same :]